# Magento Shopping Cart without shipping Charges

Tags: magento, cart

Magento 1.9.1.0 Shopping Cart is not displaying Shipping charges. After clicking on update cart shipping charges are displaying in cart.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes by default it will not add shipping charges but don't worry if you skip that on cart page, there still checkout page...

When you entered your billing address, it will add shipping charges according to that.

Comment: but its not adding on chockout page, only updating cart only reflecting shipping charges.